# How to set an IP from a specific range with dhcp?

Tags: debian, networking, dhcp, dhclient

I want to set a IP to my Debian machine using dhcp but I only want to select that IP from a specific range .
For example, my net is 10.0.100.0/24 and the range has to be from 10.0.100.90 to 10.0.100.120. How can I do this?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use `range startIP endIP` in the config. file.

Comment: Why downvote ?!